# How to use pickle to load data in a faster way?

Tags: python, save, pickle

Hi I saved my data by using pickle package in python. I did it like this:

```
save=open('slidings.txt','wb')
pickle.dump(slidings,save)
save.close()
```

The data format is like this:

```
slidings=[dic,dic,...,dic]
where dic={key1:value1, key2:value2,...}
where value is a list.
```

The resulting txt file is 18GB, which is too large to be loaded. I use the following code to load my data:

```
import pickle
df=open('slidings.txt','rb')
slidings=pickle.load(df)
df.close()
```

But it's very slow. 
Is there any alternative way to do this?
Whether an alternative way to save the data or load the data. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: A higher protocol level will help `pickle.dump(slidings, save, 4)`.

Comment: Since the "root" of the `slidings` data-structure appears to be a list of dictionaries, you could save each dictionary as a separate pickle and read them back iteratively — it's very doubtful that you need all that data in memory at the same time.

Comment: The data itself is large, is this the sort of thing that would fit in a numpy array or pandas dataframe? It has several options for saving data such as parquet that may work better.

Comment: Thank you for advices!